# Convert a Laptop to PC

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, dell-inspiron

I have a laptop, but it is not functional. The processor is dead and hence left the laptop useless, I could fix the processor, but it just is very very expensive. I was wondering, remove the RAM and Hard drive from my laptop and put it on my old PC and use it as a Desktop.

Instead of removing the parts bit by bit and making them as a PC; could I just use the hard drive and RAM as a custom built desktop? Or I am just up in the clouds with this idea?

Answer (score 3):

You probably won't be able to use the laptop RAM in a desktop as they are completely different shapes.
[image: Bigger stick is Desktop, smaller is Laptop]

However, the hard drive should be usable.  If it's a SATA drive, the connections are exactly the same as a 3.5" desktop drive.  An IDE drive will need an adapter like [this](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=7641&catargetid=320013720000066114&cadevice=c&kpid=107641&gclid=CjwKEAjw2ImsBRCnjq70n_amv14SJAChXijN-zRfTlb0nqnEKOOP3jjPAkxDvH7cgEHyxCiz8fRn6RoC1rHw_wcB).  You may also need a bracket to mount it in a regular 3.5" drive bay like [this](http://www.circotech.com/bracket-250-2-5--hdd-ssd-metal-mounting-kit-.html?gclid=CjwKEAjw2ImsBRCnjq70n_amv14SJAChXijN7SkywgSWa2KrtHZmcgJwfjFNPrK3Ed3lxsvhZLYQ5xoCMn7w_wcB).